# mapping over a list using map_if conditional on string in list name

Tags: r

I have a list which looks like:

[image]

I want to map over the lists and make modifications only to the lists which contain "MultiPolygon". These lists have many columns so I want to `pivot_longer` in order to get the same strucutre data frames as the lists with `Polygon` in its name.

I was thinkig of something along the lines of `map_if(., names(.)... contains("MultiPolygon"))`

Working on a reproducible example but the data contains many columns / rows depending on the list.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I am trying. Do you know how I can map over a list, extract the `head` and select some columns? I have this `x %>% 
  map(., ~head(.x, 2)) %>% dput()` which returns the first 2 rows in each of the lists however, in list 1 and 6 I have 1096 and 234 columns respectively. This is causing the dput to be really large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option to what @zoowalk did, is to use `grepl`. Thus, to catch every sublist name with the word "MultiPolygon".

```
library(tidyverse)
#@zoowalk sample dataset
my_list <- list(MultiPolygon_1=data.frame(x=1, y=2),
                Polyon=data.frame(x=1, y=2),
                MultiPolygon_2=data.frame(x=1, y=2))
#Solution 
map_if(my_list, 
       grepl("MultiPolygon", names(my_list)), 
       function(x) {pivot_longer(x, cols=everything())})
```

## Benchmark

Out of curiosity, I've done a benchmark to test which is faster `grepl`  or `contains`.

```
    test <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "grepl" = {
    map_if(my_list, 
           grepl("MultiPolygon", names(my_list)), 
           function(x) {pivot_longer(x, cols=everything())})},
  "contains" = {
    map_at(my_list, vars(contains("Multi")), 
           function(x) pivot_longer(x, cols=everything()))
  })

test

Unit: milliseconds
     expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
    grepl 11.9151 12.18045 13.20936 12.36950 12.80765 34.8983   100  a 
 contains 13.2055 13.48355 14.16436 13.61405 14.00760 19.7298   100   b
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_list <- list(MultiPolygon_1=data.frame(x=1, y=2),
                Polyon=data.frame(x=1, y=2),
                MultiPolygon_2=data.frame(x=1, y=2))
my_list
#> $MultiPolygon_1
#>   x y
#> 1 1 2
#> 
#> $Polyon
#>   x y
#> 1 1 2
#> 
#> $MultiPolygon_2
#>   x y
#> 1 1 2
my_list %>% 
  map_at(., vars(contains("Multi")), function(x) pivot_longer(x, cols=everything()))
#> $MultiPolygon_1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 x         1
#> 2 y         2
#> 
#> $Polyon
#>   x y
#> 1 1 2
#> 
#> $MultiPolygon_2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 x         1
#> 2 y         2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>